# LyX show hidden characters

Tags: spacing, lyx, editors, displaybreak

I can’t find any settings in LyX where I can toggle an option that would display the hidden characters, such as narrow no-break space, or really any other no-break space.

Is it not possible?

It is very annoying because the error `Unicode character undefined (U+202F)`.
I know it is possible to just declare it in the preamble, but I would like to see where such characters are, because most of the time I type them accidentally (*e.g.*, `shift + space`).

Comment: `shift + space` is just space in my lyx 2.3.6 in Linux, whereas thin space via menu or with `control+shift + space` is marked  as a thin ␣ and exported to `\,` ,whereas enter directly the unicode symbol (Ctr+Shift+u 202f  or copy & paste from another editor) show only  a small space in the screen, but anyway is exported to latex as `\,`, so this is not a problem to render it and it can be detected in the Code Pane. Thus, how you can pass a raw  U+202F to the latex code?

Comment: I have the same observations as Fran. One use case that kind of matches what you're asking about is when pasting text containing the characters (e.g., when copying from a PDF). I've been bitten by (unknowingly) pasting such characters into LyX before and not realizing it.

Comment: @Fran I don’t know… I guess my LyX did not by default export U+202F as `\,`. I had to explicitly add in my preamble with the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. In any case, I would prefer to not have such thin space in my raw LyX and in order to best accomplish that, I want to see the characters being displayed.

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{{\huge --- I AM HERE ---}}`  and for sure you will note if really there are some hidden thin space instead of  `\,`

Comment: Yes, but that will only display in the compiled PDF output. What I want is to display it in the LyX interface.